# Object Cannot be cast to streaming receiver

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spray-json

In a spark streaming application I am getting the message that one of the serializable classes I use to pass as the item class for an RDD, cannot be cast into a receiver.  I wasn't trying to cast it into a reciever, but here it is:

```
15/04/18 18:30:22 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.ClassCastException: vehicles.Vehicle_Status cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverLauncher$$anonfun$8.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:295)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.ReceiverTracker$ReceiverLauncher$$anonfun$8.apply(ReceiverTracker.scala:290)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1497)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1497)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

here is the code that is presumably getting me there:

```scala
val rmqReceiver = new RMQReceiver(qAddress, "vehicle-data")
val customReceiverStream = aContext.receiverStream(rmqReceiver)

val handler = (rdd: RDD[List[String]]) => {
  this.handleStreamResult(rdd)
}
customReceiverStream.foreachRDD(handler)
```

```scala
def jsonToVehicleStatus(aRecord :String): Vehicle_Status ={
  val ast = aRecord.parseJson
  val aMap = ast.convertTo[Vehicle_Status]
  return aMap

}

def handleStreamResult(rdd: RDD[List[String]]): Unit ={
  rdd.foreach { list =>
    val mapList = list.map(jsonToVehicleStatus)
    val pMapList = sparkContext.parallelize(mapList)

    pMapList.saveToCassandra("vehicle_data","vehicles",AllColumns)
    println()

  }
}
```

does anyone have any idea why it is trying to cast it into a receiver?